# Error at the time of running server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

while I am running my sever i am getting the below error in my console:----

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
 `require': no such file to load -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2.rb:9:in`'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:66:in`block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:55:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:11
9:in `require'
        from D:/usr/barun/project/rails/forum web service/dummy/config/applicati
on.rb:7:in`'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in`block in '
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in`'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in`'

How to solve this error i am not getting...
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. following solution worked for me

```
Solution: the libmysql.dll file is located in the bin directory of your mysql installation. This file needs to be a copy of it in the Ruby\bin directory.
```

Comment: libmysql.dll file is already present in ruby\bin directory....i tried by replacing it but still the error is same

Comment: Try this: http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Comment: Or you can also try export RUBYOPT=rubygems